# How to exclude "animate" from addEventListener "scroll"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this problem I can't wrap my head around:

I am checking if the user is scrolling the page after using the search form. In which case, the search form should unfocus, with:

```
var content = document.querySelector('.content');
    content.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    $("#search_box").blur();
});
```

Now, I also want the page to always scroll the content to the top as the user is typing, with:

```
$('#search_box').keyup(function() {

   $('.content').animate({
       scrollTop: 0
   });

}
```

As you can see, this creates a problem. The user is typing, the page scrolls automatically to the top and the search box unfocuses basically on every letter being typed, which is super annoying.

Is there any easy way to exclude `scrollTop` or `.animate` from the `addEventListener`?

I want the user being able to type, have the content scrolled to the top and when they click anywhere on the page (scrolling down manually), the search box should unfocus.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the search box only lose focus if the page is being scrolled down:

```js
var content = document.querySelector('.content');
var currentPos = content.scrollTop;

content.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    if (content.scrollTop > currentPos) {
        $('#search_box').blur();
    }
    currentPos = content.scrollTop;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could refocus on the search box after the animation is complete:

```js
$('#search_box').keyup(function() {
    $('.content').animate({
        scrollTop: 0
    }, function() {
        $('#search_box').focus();
    });
}
```